# Take 9 distinct objects and 5 identical boxes. Exactly one object must be placed into each box. In how many ways can this be done?

Tags: combinations

> Take 9 distinct objects and 5 identical boxes. Exactly one object must be placed into each box. In how many ways can this be done?

According to a similar question, I list 4 cases.

Case 1. $\quad(5,1,1,1,1):$ $\quad^9C_5 = 126$
Case 2. $\quad(4,2,1,1,1):$ $\quad^9C_4 = 126$
Case 3. $\quad(3,3,1,1,1):$ $\quad^9C_3 = 84$
Case 4. $\quad(3,2,2,1,1):$ $\quad^9C_3 = 84$

And then I add them up, but I still get the answer wrong.
Can anyone give me some hints on this question?

Comment: "*case1 (5,1,1,1,1) ...*" $\,$ None of those follow the rule that "***exactly one*** *object must be placed into each container*".

Answer (score 3):

Since the boxes are *identical* and *exactly* one object must be placed in each,
simply $\binom95 = 126$ ways

Comment: Why not multiply 5!?

Comment: Because the boxes are **identical**. If they were **distinct**, then we would multiply by $5!$

Comment: Aight. Thanks. !

Comment: @insipidintegrator: You're welcome !